# What is meant by "low-lying" electronic states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, electronic-band-theory, laser-interaction, free-electron-lasers

In the context of electronic structure and spectroscopy, the term "low-lying electronic states" is quite common but it really isn't defined anywhere. All google search results lead to research papers that just use the term. So my question is, what does it exactly mean? why are they "low"?

Are they "low" because they are:

1. close to the ground state?
2. within the valence band?
3. close to the valence band?
   etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally take low lying states to mean close to the ground state of the total system. For electronic systems this will amount to the lowest unoccupied states, whatever they may be for your particular system

Comment: Clarification: what do you mean by "electronic systems"

Comment: Systems of many  electrons (metals, semiconductors etc) as opposed to say systems of spins, bosons, atomic gases or whatever else

Comment: Ah thanks! Another follow-up, why the LUMO and not the HOMO? I imagine that it's the HOMO that changes per system that affects its properties. The LUMO is unoccupied so it shouldn't do anything?

Comment: The LUMO represent states that an electron can be excited into, so states where the LUMO is occupied would (typically) be low-lying states, but not the ground state